# создать прямоугольник со скошенной стороной. При изменении угла наклона должен меняться угол наклона текста

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно сделать такой вот блок со скошенным углом. Угол наклона можнобудет поменять в админке и при изменении уровня наклона должен и текст наклоняться..

Comment: А можно увидеть код ?
Не говоря уже о js...

Comment: Я бы хотела получить просто совет как это можно реализовать.я сначала сделала просто белый треугольник, который лежит сверху. да, так нормально получается регулировать угол наклона, но на текст никак не влияет. Мне бы хотя бы просто в теории понять в каком направлении двигаться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут матрёшка, первый блок у которого `overflow:hidden`, в нем другой блок который повернут через `transform: rotate(-5deg);` а внутри него уже блок с текстом.

```js
function rotate(deg){
  document.querySelector('div.block > div')
          .style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(${deg}deg)`;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

div.block {
  position:absolute;
  height:170px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div.block > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 130px); 
  left: 50%;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 350px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
             rotate(-5deg);
  text-align:center;
  background-color:wheat;
}

div.block  > div > div {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0; 
 left:50%;
 font-size:30px;
 font-family:arial;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0) 
}
```

```html
<input type="range" from="0" to="100" value="0" onmousemove="rotate((this.value/100-0.5)*10)"/>
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <div>Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```